# Refetch data from firestore db after its updates

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm working on a project where I fetch data from firebase firestore db and storage. Currently it fetches on a component render, so it doesn't refetch when data updates i need firstly to reload my page. I'm looking for a solution where i can listen to db changes and fetch when data updates.

Here is an example of my code:

Hook:

```
export const useGetUsers = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<Users[] | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
    const userData: Users[] = [];

    await Promise.all(
      querySnapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
        const avatarPath: StorageReference = ref(
          storage,
          `users-avatars/${doc.data().uid}`
        );
        try {
          const avatarUrl = await getDownloadURL(avatarPath);
          userData.push({
            ...doc.data(),
            avatar: avatarUrl,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          userData.push({
            ...doc.data(),
            avatar: "",
          });
        }
      })
    );

    return userData;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const data = await fetchUsers();
      setUsers(data);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return { users, loading };
};
```

Component

```
export const ProfileBar = () => {
  const { currentUser, loading } = useGetCurrentUser();
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a solution where I can listen to db changes and fetch
> when data updates.

This is exactly the goal of the [Firestore realtime listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

As explained in this documentation (above link):

> You can listen to a document with the `onSnapshot()` method. An initial
> call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot
> immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then,
> each time the contents change, another call updates the document
> snapshot.
>
> ...
>
> As with documents, you can use `onSnapshot()` to listen to the results of a query. This creates a query snapshot. The snapshot handler will receive a new query snapshot every time the query results change (that is, when a document is added, removed, or modified).